# Duda sobre el diseño de una base de datos en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Por favor quisiera su ayuda para terminar de diseñar mi base de datos, el contexto es el siguiente:

- Un usuario empezará creando una nueva consultoría, la consultoría pedirá que seleccioné una norma, dicha norma tiene numerales y cada numeral tiene unos requerimientos, pero sucede que para una consultoría puede que no apliquen todos los numerales o que no aplique todos los requerimientos, además de eso, el usuario podrá definir el nivel de importancia que tiene un requerimiento y por último a cada requerimiento se le puede asignar una actividad.

*Cuando digo "norma" me refiero a un documento que determina la implementación de un sistema de gestión en una empresa, por ejemplo: La norma ISO 9001, dicha norma tiene sus numerales, que serian los títulos enumerados y dentro de cada numeral hay requerimientos, esos requerimientos los deben cumplir las empresas, pero como los cumplen? Realizando actividades, ¿okey? Pero sucede que hay requerimientos que no les aplican a todas las empresas, así como también hay numerales que no aplican para todas las empresas.*

Entonces, con base en el anunciado anterior, yo me imagino que deben existir 5 tablas `usuarios`, `normas`, `numerales`, `requirimientos` y `actividades`, así que tengo el siguiente modelo:

(Ampliar la imagen)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Nota: Estoy obviando la tabla `users`.***

Bueno, para explicar el modelo de una forma rápida seria:

**Tenemos una tabla `consultancies` que tiene una relación de uno a muchos con la tabla `norms`**

**Cardinalidad:** Una consultoria puede tener asignada una norma, pero una norma puede estar presente en varias consultorias.

---

**Tenemos otra tabla `norms` que tiene una relación de uno a muchos con la tabla `numerals`**

**Cardinalidad:** Una norma puede tener muchos numerales, pero un numeral solo puede estar presente en una norma a la vez.

---

**Tenemos otra tabla `numerals` que tiene una relación de uno a muchos con la tabla `requirements`**

**Cardinalidad:** Un numeral puede tener muchos requerimientos, pero un requerimiento solo puede estar presente en un numeral a la vez.

---

**Tenemos otra tabla `activities` que tiene una relación de uno a muchos con la tabla `requirements`**

**Cardinalidad:** Un requerimiento puede tener muchas actividades asignadas, pero una actividad solo puede estar en un requerimiento a la vez.

---

Ahora adjunto una imagen de las tablas con registros (Ampliar la imagen)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En caso de que la imagen no se pueda ver bien, anexo un link a la misma imagen pero en formato PDF para mayor calidad: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RMGPr9UoSft42yZY0Y7e1mESnM0AciQI/view?usp=sharing

Explicándolo de otra forma sería algo así:  En la tabla consultorías creamos una nueva consultoría, a esa consultoría se le asigna una norma, entonces con base en la norma, me traigo los numerales y de cada numeral me traigo los requerimientos, luego a cada requerimiento le asigno una o muchas actividades.

Pero si vamos al enunciado, dice que para una consultoría puede que NO todos los numerales y requerimientos apliquen, algunos me dirán que debería crear una nueva columna "status" en la tabla `numerals` y `requirements` para validar si aplican o no, pero yo no puedo hacer eso, porque allí estaría definiendo el estado para todas las consultorías que se creen con base en dicha norma o requerimiento, **¿Entonces, cuál es el objetivo?** El objetivo por el que hago esta pregunta, es porque quiero que esto sea dinámico, que cuando el usuario cree una consultoría, pueda escoger la norma y posteriormente decidir que numerales o que requerimientos aplican o no aplican.

Espero que se haya entendido. Muchas gracias, ojalá me puedan ayudar.

### EDIT: modificaciones después de recibir ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para concluir, se generaron dos tablas más, `consultancy_numeral` y `consultancy_requirement`, la creación de estas tablas relacionales solventan mi problema principal, así podre validar si un numeral o un requerimiento aplica o no aplica para una consultoría en específico.

Espero que esto les sirva a otras personas.

Comment: a lo mejor esta pregunta estaría mejor en https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Podríamos ayudarte si se entendiera el contexto que intentas modelar. De entrada se me hace muy extraña esa cascada de tablas aunque, como no conozco la semántica, tal vez podría estar bien. Asumo que no, simplemente porque pides ayuda. Tal vez si añadieras registros de ejemplo que ilustraran un poco el problema...

Comment: @JavierG.Raya hice la pregunta también allá,  gracias.

Comment: @DavidJP vale voy subir otra imagen con registros en las tablas, gracias.

Comment: @DavidJP creo que mejoré la explicación, puedes revisar si logras entender? Más luego subo la imagen con registros en las tablas.

Comment: @JesúsOrozco, no me refería a que me definieras las cardinalidades, sino a que explicaras un poco qué intentas modelar. Para eso los datos ayudan bastante. Piensa que un diseñador de bases de datos no tiene por qué saber cómo se organiza esta consultoría ni qué es un numeral. Si le cuentas qué es cada concepto, podría ayudarte :)

Comment: @DavidJP Hola David, gracias por seguir presente, ya subí la imagen de las tablas con registros, te sugiero que mejor lo abras en pdf, ahí te anexé un link, estoy pendiente, muchas gracias!

Comment: @JesúsOrozco, entiendo que no puedas revelar información sensible. Los datos pueden ser ficticios, pero deben tener sentido para el diseñador. No se trata de rellenar las tablas con un Lorem Ipsum como si estuviéramos probando una maquetación, son tipos de diseño muy diferentes.

Comment: En el modelado de datos la semántica es muy importante porque es la que define las relaciones y cardinalidades entre las entidades. Si no sé qué datos quieres guardar, no puedo determinar si necesitas una relación de grado dos o cuatro, si `numerals` es una entidad o una relación, o si todo está relacionado directamente con `consultancies`.

Comment: Cuando alguien necesita relacionar clientes con proveedores, almacén y facturas, como todos esos conceptos son conocidos, no hay problema en modelarlos; pero si te pido que me modeles una base de datos para almacenar aguacates, tulipas, numerales y tornillos, pues a ver cómo te arreglas sin tener ni idea de cómo podemos meter todos esos conceptos en una misma frase con sentido. En definitiva: define qué es cada entidad y podremos ayudarte :)

Comment: Okey entiendo tu punto @DavidJP

Cuando digo "norma" me refiero a un documento que determina la implementación de un sistema de gestión en una empresa, por ejemplo: La norma ISO 9001, dicha norma tiene sus numerales, que serian los títulos enumerados y dentro de cada numeral hay requerimientos, esos requerimientos los deben cumplir las empresas, pero como los cumplen? Realizando actividades, ¿okey? Pero sucede que hay requerimientos que no les aplican a todas las empresas, así como también hay numerales que no aplican para todas las empresas.

¿Ahora está más claro? De nuevo, gracias! :)

Comment: Y para mí las tablas: consultorías, normas, numerales, requerimientos y actividades son entidades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo, en este caso lo que necesitas es recurrir al concepto de abstracción que te permite vincular directamente dos relaciones para obtener algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la práctica, únicamente necesitas añadir 3 tablas que registren qué numerales, requerimientos y actividades específicas debería cumplir cada consultoría.

Estas tablas se rellenan fácilmente porque las vinculaciones genéricas ya las tienes definidas en las tablas que ya tienes creadas. Tan sólo tienes que confirmar cada posibilidad entre las genéricas y así concretarla para cada consultoría.

Ya lo puedes dejar bien documentado, porque a ver quién se acuerda de esta pirueta... :)

## Respuestas a los comentarios

### Abstracciones

Lo encerrar `normas`, `r` y `numerales` en un recuadro es una *abstracción* para conceptualmente convertir ese bloque en un entidad y poder vincularlo con `consultorias` a través de la relación `c_num`. Según el modelo de Chen no se puden vincular directamente ni dos entidades, ni dos relaciones. Habría que hacer lo mismo con los bloques `numerales`, `r` y `requerimientos`, así como con `requerimientos`, `r` y `actividades`. No lo he hecho para no sobrecargar el diagrama. En resumen: son detallitos teóricos, no pierdas mucho tiempo en ellos.

### Propagación

Las relaciones que he denominado `r` no es necesario que las conviertas en tablas, tal y como lo tienes está perfecto. La explicación teórica a esta cuestión está basada en la cardinalidad: al ser 1:N, puedes llevarte el campo `id_norma` a la tabla `numerales` y, aunque en el modelo ER tiene que existir la relación, se pueden omitir las tablas `r` si propagas el campo `id` que proceda.

### Tablas apply

Tal vez te falte una tabla `consultancy_activities` para llevar el control de las actividades que iría realizando o tiene que realizar cada consultoría para dar cumplimiento a los requerimientos del numeral correspondiente de la norma. Pero eso ya lo sabrás tú mejor que yo.

Sin la tabla `cumplen`, tal y como lo tienes, cada consultoría únicamente podría cumplir una norma. ¿Esto sería correcto?

### Finalización de la pregunta

Para dejar la pregunta bien documentada y que le pueda resultar útil a alguien más en el futuro, edita la pregunta y copia los comentarios aclaratorios, sobre todo el último.

Si tienes dificultades con las consultas que tienes que realizar para controlar el grado de cumplimiento de cada empresa, crea una pregunta nueva y no te olvides de adjuntar la estructura de las tablas implicadas en SQL con phpadmin->exportar, por ejemplo.

Comment: Uy amigo, muchísimas gracias, ya tengo más claridad en este tipo de relaciones.

Una última pregunta, porque encierras la entidad, normas y numerales en un cuadro?

Comment: Hice un EDIT a la pregunta y añadí la imagen de la base de datos con las sugerencias que me diste, solo me falta agregar la relación entre consultoría y actividades, pero así como voy, está bien, no?

Comment: Hay tablas extras que agregué en este último edit., pero no les hagas caso, solo quiero que veas las relaciones con la tabla consultancies :)

Comment: Gracias por todas las aclaraciones, ya volví a editar mi pregunta con la solución, muy agradecido con usted..